# The Jacobson Radical of a Matrix Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I am trying to solve the following question.

> Let $A$ be the algebra over $\mathbb{C}$ consisting of matrices of the form
>   \begin{pmatrix}
> * & * & 0 & 0 \\
> * & * & 0 & 0 \\
> * & * & * & 0 \\
> * & * & * & * \\
> \end{pmatrix}
>   Find the Jacobson radical of $A$.

To be honest I don't really have any idea how to do this so any help would very much be appreciated!

Comment: Basically the same as [this other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1049982/29335), although not exactly the same ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [that post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88284/left-and-right-ideals-of-r-left-bigl-beginsmallmatrixab-0c-endsmallm/137526#137526) again here!

The construction there uses an $R-S$ bimodule to create the ring: $T=\begin{pmatrix}
 R & M \\
 0 & S \\
\end{pmatrix}$ with formal matrix multiplication as the product. We can use the same thing here, except we can use an $S-R$ bimodule in the lower left corner: $T=\begin{pmatrix}
 R & 0 \\
 M & S \\
\end{pmatrix}$.  In your case, $R=M=M_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $S$ is the subring of lower triangular matrices of $R$.

Applying (analogous) info from "that post", we have $rad(T)=\begin{pmatrix}
 rad(R) & 0 \\
 M & rad(S) \\
\end{pmatrix}$.

**Can you take it from here?**

Extra tools to keep in mind when doing things like this:

- if $I$ is a nilpotent (one or two sided) ideal, then $I \subseteq rad(R)$.
- if $R/I$ is semisimple, then $rad(R)\subseteq I$.

Check and see what you get when you compute $T/rad(T)$ for your example! :)

Comment: Thanks again for another brilliant answer! I am pretty sure I have understood everything you have said in this post!

Comment: @AlexKite How about you write up your solution, and whatever else you found useful, here in another answer?