# A Jacobson radical of a matrix ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

What is the Jacobson radical of the ring $R=\left [\begin{array}\ \mathbb Z_2 & \mathbb Z_2\\ 0 & \mathbb Z_4 \end{array} \right ]$? I think it is $\left [\begin{array}\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\mathbb Z_4 \end{array} \right ]$, but I am not sure. Could any body tells me how to obtain the radical? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had you searched a bit, you would almost certainly have found one of these:

[Jacobson radical of a certain ring of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1049982/29335)

[Jacobson radical of upper triangular matrix rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2097740/29335)

[Jacobson radical of a matrix ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2027555/29335)

[Jacobson radical of upper triangular matrix rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2097740/29335)

They all carry sufficient explanation to explain why the radical of this ring is

\begin{bmatrix}
0&\mathbb Z_2 \\
0& 2\mathbb Z_4
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: (I had intended to convey that in an ideal world it would've considered a duplicate, but I thought it would borderline to close as such in this case.)