# Jacobson radical of group rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

[image]

$4 b)$

(i) Any hints?

(ii) Well $R$ is not semi-simple since $|\mathbb{Z}/3|=3=0 \in F_3$ by the converse of Maschke's theorem.

(iii) The surjective $\mathbb{C}$-algebra map $\phi:R \to M_2(\mathbb{C})\times\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}: (a_{i,j}) \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}       & a_{12} \\
    a_{21}       & a_{22} 
\end{bmatrix},a_{33},a_{44}$ has nilpotent kernel and semi-simple target.Hence the kernel is the Jacobson radical i.e. \begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 0 & *  & * \\
    0      & 0 & * & * \\
    0      & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0 & 0  & 0
\end{bmatrix}

Sample solution that may help with iii)
[image]

Comment: can you give me a reference of these problems. It seems very interesting and worth trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) If you know Maschke's theorem (as you hint in (ii)) then you already know the answer to this since the order of $D_8$ is $8$.

(ii) Yes. And it would not even be too hard to exhibit some nonzero nilpotent element to prove that the Jacobson radical is nonzero.

(iii) You can use exactly the same logic [here at this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1050265/29335).  I'm not sure about your attempt. A surjective homomorphism from $R\to M_2(\mathbb C)\times \mathbb C\times \mathbb C$ would have a six dimensional image and a $6$ dimensional kernel (not $4$ dimensional).  But part of the logic at the other post confirms that you can find a homomorphism onto $M_2(\mathbb C)\times M_2(\mathbb C)$, which has and $8$-dimensional image and the $4$-dimensional kernel you describe. Since the quotient has Jacobson radical zero, that is *excactly* the Jacobson radical of $R$, then.

Comment: Why would it have a six dimensional image?

Comment: @Walter ... because $M_2(\mathbb C)$ is four dimensional and the two extra $\mathbb C$'s only add two more dimensions? If the kernel had four dimensions, you wouldn't be able to fit the remaining $8$ dimensions of the image into this ring.

Comment: Also, answer to (i) is $0$ since $R$ is semi-simple?

Comment: @Walter I think that you could write a solution for both questions in the style of that solution OR in the style that you want to do. It should work either way. You need to tell me about the homomorphism before I can help.  (and YES about the answer of (i) you proposed in the last comment.)

Comment: @Walter Sorry, I don't click weird links. You can just tell me the map if you want.

Comment: Check the OP thanks

Comment: @Walter Sorry, the description of the homomorphism went right by me last time. Yes, your solution to the slightly-different problem works perfectly. The problem is that you've miscomputed the kernel in the original solution. The kernel is $\{\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&\ast&\ast \\0&0&\ast&\ast\\ 0&0&0&\ast \\ 0&0&\ast&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]\}$, and that isn't nilpotent. See? If you switch to the homomorphism that maps the $2\times 2$ diagonal blocks onto $M_2(\mathbb C)\times M_2(\mathbb C)$ then your idea works.

Comment: I see my kernel is wrong. What diagonal blocks?

Comment: @Walter do to the lower right hand $2\times 2$ what you did with the upper left hand $2\times 2$, of course

Comment: Should I make a new question to ask about bii)? I understand i) and iii) now but ii) comes up a lot but I don't understand it totally.

Comment: @Walter I don't think it deserves a whole new post. When the order of the group is not coprime with the characteristic, the sum of all elements of the group is a nilpotent element and it is also central, so the ideal generated by it is nilpotent too, and semisimple rings do not have such ideals.