# Simple modules of an algebra

Tags: noncommutative-algebra

How can we find the simple modules of this algebra $$
\begin{pmatrix} 
k & 0 &0  \\
k & k & 0 \\
k&0&k
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And why this algebra is not semisimple(i,e it is isomorphic to the algebra $k^{5}$????)
I know that his radical is $$
\begin{pmatrix} 
0& 0&0 \\
k& 0&0 \\
k&0&0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> How can we find the simple modules of this algebra

Denoting this algebra as $R$, the simple $R$ modules are exactly the simple $R/J(R)$ modules, where $J(R)$ is the Jacobson radical you have found. This is isomorphic to the product ring $k^3$. Now you just need to conclude what the isoclasses of simple modules over *that* ring are.

The same strategy was applied at this solution, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/147195/29335

> And why this algebra is not semisimple

You just said that the Jacobson radical is some nonzero set, but the Jacobson radical of a semisimple ring is zero.

> i,e it is isomorphic to the algebra $k^5$????)

There is more than one semisimple $k$ algebra than $k^5$. It could have been $M_2(k)\times k$ or $Q\times k$ if $k$ admits a $4$-dimensional quaternion $k$-algebra other than $M_2(k)$.

Comment: The simple modules of $k^{3}$ are isomorphic to $k^{3}/m$ where $m$ is a maximal ideal of $k^{3}$??

Comment: So we have just one simple module, $k$!

Comment: @DiegoHavez *just one simple module* That is incorrect. There are, in fact, three nonisomorphic classes of simple modules.

Comment: @DiegoHavez *The simple modules of $k^3$ are isomorphic to $k^3/m$ where $m$ is a maximal ideal of  $k^3$?* That is correct.

Comment: Because we have three maximal ideals?

Comment: $ K \textsf{X}0\textsf{X}K$ $0\textsf{X}K\textsf{X}K$ $K\textsf{X}K\textsf{X}0$

Comment: I don't understand why three nonisomorphic?

Comment: rschwieb can you explain to me why?

Comment: The maximal ideals of \begin{pmatrix} 
k & 0 &0  \\
0& k & 0 \\
0&0&k
\end{pmatrix} are \begin{pmatrix} 
k & 0 &0  \\
0 & k & 0 \\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 
k & 0 &0  \\
0& 0 & 0 \\
0&0&k
\end{pmatrix} and \begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 0 &0  \\
0 & k & 0 \\
0&0&k
\end{pmatrix}. But why three nonisomorphic simple modules? they have the same dimension non!

Comment: @DiegoHavez Yes, those are the maximal ideals. You can plainly see they have different annihilators. They are not the same modules over the ring. Having the same $k$-dimension has almost nothing to do with their $R$ structure.

Comment: I finally accept lol