# Show $R$ is right-Artinian but not left-Artinian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be the subring of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by
$$R=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{pmatrix}\mid a\in\mathbb{Q},b,d\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$

Show that $R$ is right-Artinian but not left-Artinian.

The "obvious" approach to show it is not left-Artinian is to find an $A\in R$ such that
$$RA\supset R(A^2)\supset R(A^3)\supset\dots$$

is an infinite decreasing chain of proper left submodules of $R$ (as a module over itself). However, after spending a lot of time in this endeavor I've come to the conclusion that no such element $A$ exists (I can post a proof if anybody is interested but it'd be long and not worth the time for me otherwise). Does anybody have an idea for another approach I can take to this? I have no idea what else submodules of $R$ would look like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Bad news

It is impossible to prove it with the strategy you chose: in fact $R$ is a [perfect ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring), and it is known that perfect rings satisfy the DCC on principal ideals. Your descending chain of ideals will therefore have to be more sophisticated.

### Triangular rings

The ideal structure of this type of construction is explained in both of the following posts, but the second one is a slightly better fit:

[Is there a nice way to classify the ideals of the ring of lower triangular matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/158980/29335)

[Left and right ideals of $R=\left\{\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\0&c \end{smallmatrix}\bigr) : a\in\mathbb Z, \ b,c\in\mathbb Q\right\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/88284/29335)

Following the description in the latter post, we think of the ring as $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ with funny multiplication.

$J(R)$ is clearly $\begin{bmatrix}0&\Bbb R\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ since this set is a nilpotent ideal and the quotient by this set is clearly ring isomorphic to $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb R$.

### Homing in on where the chain is

Of course, basic module theory says that $R$ is left Artinian iff $R/J(R)$ and $J(R)$ are left Artinian $R$ modules. But $R/J(R)$ is just a direct sum of two simple left $R$ modules, so it is clearly Artinian. Therefore it's clear we just need to prove $J(R)$ is not a left Artinian $R$ module.

Following this line of thought, we get the idea to look for an infinite descending chain in $\{0\}\times \Bbb R\times \{0\}$.

### Apply the result on ideal structure

$\Bbb R$ is an infinite dimensional $\Bbb Q$ module, so we can find an infinite descending chain of $\Bbb Q$ submodules: index them $N_1\supset N_2\supset\ldots$. Reading from the second link, we need to make sure $MJ_2$ is a subset of our $J_1$, so to make things easy we'll just let $J_2=\{0\}$ so that this is satisfied. (The only other choice is $J_2=\Bbb R$, and that won't do.)

Now if we set $N'_i=\{0\}\times N_i\times\{0\}$, we clearly have an infinite descending sequence of $\Bbb Q$ submodules of $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb R$ containing $MJ_2=\{0\}\times\{0\}\times\{0\}$. Thus $N'_i$ furnishes an infinite descending chain of left ideals of $R$.

You could also make an infinite ascending chain of left ideals in the same way, showing it's not left Noetherian.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for this.