# Determine the left ideals of the matrix ring $A\subseteq M_2(\mathbb{R})$ with matrices of only three potentially non-zero elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals

Determine the left ideals of the matrix ring $A \subseteq M_2(\mathbb{R})$ where $$A=\{\begin{pmatrix}
  \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R}\\ 
  0 & \mathbb{R}
\end{pmatrix}\}$$ and the multiplication is the usual matrix multiplication. It looks to me as if there are only 4 ideals. Basically the matrices spanned by \begin{pmatrix}
  \mathbb{0} & \mathbb{R}\\ 
  0 & \mathbb{R}
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
  \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{0}\\ 
  0 & \mathbb{0}
\end{pmatrix} and \begin{pmatrix}
  \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R}\\ 
  0 & \mathbb{0}
\end{pmatrix} respectively and perhaps the ideals $\{0\}$ and $A$. I just want to be sure I'm not missing any. All feedback is appreciated.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2724153/apply-lams-theorem-to-determine-all-the-left-ideals-of-beginpmatrix-mathbb?rq=1).

Comment: For a fixed $\lambda\neq 0$, the set of matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}x&\lambda x\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is a left ideal, and there are infinitely many of that form.  If you take a look at the duplicate, this corresponds to the case of $I_2=\{0\}$ and $I_1$ just being some subspace of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$.