# Ideals of the subring $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}$ of $M_2(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

The set $A$ of all lower triangular $2\times 2$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb Z$ is a subring of $M_2(\mathbb Z)$. However, what are its ideals? I couldn't find them.

Suppose $I$ is an ideal of $A$. The elements of $I$, being also elements of $A$ have to be lower triangular and $I$ should be closed under left and right multiplication by lower triangular matrices. These facts couldn't lead me anywhere.

Edit: I saw [the other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/158980/161825) and the answer there went far above my head. I have no idea what a module is. Please help me do this without resorting to all of those advanced technique

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in \mathcal{A} \iff b = 0$

Comment: @krirkrirk yeah?

Comment: What I meant is you need to check when $AB \in I$ for $B\in I$ and $A \in \mathcal{A}$, not for $A\in M_2(\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: @krirkrirk just realized this. Thanks. I updated the question.

Comment: rschwieb gives a good answer at the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158980/is-there-a-nice-way-to-classify-the-ideals-of-the-ring-of-lower-triangular-matri). I don't think it can be made easier. You do not need module theory to see the result.