# Showing a certain ring is right Noetherian and not left Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, noetherian

How can I prove that the ring of all $2*2$ matrices $$S=\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & c
\end{bmatrix} \qquad 
\end{equation*}$$

Such that $a$ is an integer and $b,c$ are rationals is right Noetherian but not left Noetherian. I have seen a lot of discussions here about it but I still did not understand it, could anyone give me a clear and simple answer to it please?

**Edit**
My professor answer was as follows:

These are the right ideals of $S$ (and I do not know why), $\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
n\mathbb{Z} & Q \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \qquad 
\end{equation*}$, $\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
n\mathbb{Z} & Q \\
0 & Q
\end{bmatrix} \qquad 
\end{equation*}$, $\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & Q \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \qquad 
\end{equation*}$, $\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & Q \\
0 & Q
\end{bmatrix} \qquad 
\end{equation*}$, $\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & Q
\end{bmatrix} \qquad 
\end{equation*}$, $\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
n\mathbb{Z} & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \qquad 
\end{equation*}$, and she said and because $\mathbb{Z}$ is Noetherian $S$ is right Noetherian.

Then she calculated the following (and I do not know why):

$\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{Z} & Q \\
0 & Q
\end{bmatrix} \qquad 
\end{equation*}$$\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
n & q \\
0 & p
\end{bmatrix} \qquad 
\end{equation*} =  $\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
n\mathbb{Z} & q\mathbb{Z} + pQ \\
0 & pQ
\end{bmatrix} \qquad 
\end{equation*}

And she said so if $q \in Q,$
 $\begin{equation*}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & q\mathbb{Z} \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \qquad 
\end{equation*}$ is a left ideal of $S$.

Then she added if $n >1,$

$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n} \subsetneq \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n^2} \subsetneq ...... $$

Really I did not understand how she is thinking and how she is organizing her answer, could anyone explain her answer to me (she is inpatient professor this is why I did not ask her  )

Comment: See also the solution [here](http://planetmath.org/exampleofarightnoetherianringthatisnotleftnoetherian).

Comment: You asked for a hint at the duplicate, and got links to two questions which give you everything you need to solve the problem. If you have a question about the links you should ask in a comments of those questions, not just post the same question again asking for a complete answer instead of a hint.

Comment: @rschwieb  my professor answered it in a so different way this is why I am shocked ..... I think the better thing that I should do is to post my professor answer so that I could discuss it with others because I am not fully convinced with it.

Comment: @Intuition Sure, if you thought the proof had a gap you could probably formulate a post around the problem.

Comment: @rschwieb  I have edited my question ..... could you please see it if you have time?

Comment: @Intuition Thank you for improving your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> These are the right ideals (I do not know why)

As I mentioned when you asked this question previously, [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/137526/29335) explains what all the right ideals are. Just follow the description of right ideals at the link, and you can see.

It is a good exercise to prove that characterization of right ideals too. It simply amounts to reasoning what a right ideal must contain if you are multiplying with things like $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ on the right.

Then finally, after studying that solution, see why $R$ is right Noetherian: you have an exact sequence $0\to \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&\mathbb Q\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb Z&\mathbb Q\\0&\mathbb Q\end{bmatrix}\to\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb Z&\mathbb Q\\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}\to 0$ of $R$ modules, and the point is that both halves are Noetherian. But that means the thing in the middle is Noetherian too. (Hint: any nonzero submodule of the right hand module is generated by $\begin{bmatrix}n&0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ for some $n$.  The left hand module is a $\mathbb Q$ module via the action of $R$ and is 1-dimensional.)

> Then she calculated the following (and I do not know why)

That computation is shorthand for what it looks like to multiply something of the form $\begin{bmatrix}n&q\\0&p\end{bmatrix}$ on the left by an arbitrary element of the ring. If you consider the subset of elements with $n=p=0$, then this proves that  $
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & q\mathbb{Z} \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
$ is a left ideal of $S$, since it is an additive subgroup which absorbs multiplication on the left. That much is reasonable.

> Then she added if $n >1,$
> $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n} \subsetneq \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n^2} \subsetneq ...... $

This, without more explanation, is a little unclear, but the goal should be apparent: we must find a sequence of strictly increasing left ideals of $R$. The chain written here is not a sequence of ideals in anything we are looking at... it looks like a sequence of quotients of $\mathbb Z$. Based on the last observation, all we need to do is find a strictly increasing sequence of left ideals of the form $
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & q\mathbb{Z} \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
$
and this is easily obtained by letting $q\in\{\frac1n,\frac1{n^2},\frac1{n^3},\frac1{n^4}\ldots \}$

Comment: And thank you for your patience in answering me ...... I am from a developing country where the people(including me) are scientifically poor ..... forgive me if sometimes my questions lack of context ...... in our countries we learn thinking accidentally and not in a rigor way.

Comment: If $R$ in your answer is the same ring $S$ in the question, I do not see how $\begin{bmatrix}\mathbb Z&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ is a right $R$-module.

Comment: @khashayar You are right! That is a mistake. I think i have repaired it.